# Applying background on edittext

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to apply background(a `Drawable`) on an `EditText` but, the `Drawable`  somehow gets a white background. Here is my `Drawable` background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="4sp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape>
```

Here is the EditText I want to apply the background to :

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mEditTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_search_back"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

This is the result I get.

[image: The result]

I just want the `Drawable` to be applied as the background to the `EditText` and not the white box in the background.

Comment: Trying changing stroke color to transparent or black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_search_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mEditTextSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_search_back"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```